# how can i show the upload image on screen

Tags: reactjs

in this, I have uploaded the image but I want to preview the image before uploading it how can I do that in react js.can any one give me the help by giving the answer or by giving me a sample program  I am posting my code can anyone help me with it I am stuck with it for a long time. The code is given below:

```
const { REACT_APP_SERVER_URL } = process.env;

function UserForm(props) {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
    setValue,
  } = useForm({ defaultValues: props.item });

  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  const getRoleData = () => {
    const baseURL = `${REACT_APP_SERVER_URL}/apis/role/all`;
    axios.get(baseURL).then((response) => {
      setItems(response.data.data);
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getRoleData();
  }, []);

  const uploadPhoto = (e) => {
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = () => {
      setValue('photo', reader.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }

  return (
    <form className="userForm">
      <div className="form-group">
        
        <label htmlFor="photo">Profile Photo</label>
        <input
          type="file"
          accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg"
          className="form-control"
          name="photo"
          onChange={(e) => uploadPhoto(e)}
          placeholder="Enter your office photo "
          // {...register("photo")}
        />
        {errors.photo && (
          <p className="text-danger">Photo is required</p>
        )}
      </div>
      <div className="form-group mt-4">
        {!props.viewItem && props.view && (
          <Button
            onClick={handleSubmit(props.submitHandler)}
            variant="contained"
            className="btn1"
          >
            {props.editItem ? "Update" : "Add"}
          </Button>
        )}

        <Button
          variant="contained"
          className="btn1"
          onClick={() => {
            props.setShowAddUser(false);
            props.setItem("");
          }}
        >
          Cancel
        </Button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}

export default UserForm;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
import {useState } from "react";

// useState
const [file, setFile] = useState("");

// input
<input
    type="file"
    id="file"
    onChange={(e) => setFile(e.target.files[0])}
/>

// preview
<img src={file ? URL.createObjectURL(file) : "https://default-image.jpg"} alt="" />
```